# What is the Evolved Expendable Launch Vehicle (EELV) Secondary Payload Adapter (ESPA) Augmented Geosynchronous Laboratory Experiment satellite?

Tags: geostationary, military, secondary-payload

The Spaceflight Now article [Multi-satellite payload hoisted into high-altitude orbit by Atlas 5 rocket](https://spaceflightnow.com/2018/04/15/multi-satellite-stack-hoisted-into-high-altitude-orbit-by-atlas-5-rocket/) includes the passage:

> **The lower passenger is the Evolved Expendable Launch Vehicle (EELV) Secondary Payload Adapter (ESPA) Augmented Geosynchronous Laboratory Experiment satellite. The Air Force calls the nested acronym EAGLE for short** (emphasis added).
>
> Orbital ATK developed the EAGLE spacecraft by modifying a ring-like structure often used to connect small satellites to their launchers, adding solar panels, computers, rocket thrusters and instrumentation to the adapter. The Air Force says EAGLE will a pathfinder for future missions, demonstrating a maneuverable satellite design that could help the military launch new capabilities at less cost.
>
> Managed by the Air Force Research Laboratory’s space vehicles directorate at Kirtland Air Force Base, New Mexico, the EAGLE mission “hosts experiments designed to detect, identify, and attribute threatening behavior as well as enhance space situational awareness,” the Air Force said in a statement.

The phrase "Evolved Expendable Launch Vehicle (EELV) Secondary Payload Adapter (ESPA) Augmented Geosynchronous Laboratory Experiment satellite" has got me dazed and confused, more in the Led Zeppelin than the Matthew McConaughey kind of way.

Can someone sort this out for me? Is this one long name or are there separate components included in this phrase?

Comment: Wow, it's a triple portmanteau acronym! Good find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're just asking about the acronym, I can break that down for you.

[image]

Comment: I see you have some operational experience with acronymology.